# Tkinter Show webcam view in second window

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I am using a webcam view and performing analysis on the images taken in. I wish to introduce a functionality where a window can be summoned and the user can look at the webcam view in a new window, should they desire. However my attempt causes buttons in my main window to swap over to the instance when I open up the new window. What's going wrong?

Here is my (working) example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class CamView():  
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.window = tk.Toplevel(parent)

        self.window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close) 
        self.show_frame()

    def show_frame(self):
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.parent.img)
        lmain.imgtk = imgtk
        lmain.configure(image=imgtk)

    def close(self):
        self.parent.test_frame = None
        self.window.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: root.quit())
lmain = tk.Label(root)
lmain.pack()

class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.test_frame = None
        frame = tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        a = tk.Label(text='hello!').pack()
        b = tk.Button(frame, text='open', command=self.load_window)
        b.pack()

        width, height = 800, 600
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
        self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)

        self.do_stuff()

    def do_stuff(self):
        _, frame = self.cap.read()
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        self.img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)

        if self.test_frame != None:
            self.test_frame.show_frame()
        lmain.after(10, self.do_stuff)

    def load_window(self):
        self.test_frame = CamView(self)

control = Main(root)
root.mainloop()
```

In my real code, as well as this working example - it seems that when I load the new window, it places the webcam frame in the first window when I don't want it to!

Comment: I don't have a camera or cv2 so I can't run your code or offer much help on this mysterious problem, unfortunately. However, you should make `CamView` a new-style class using `class CamView(object):`. This change probably won't affect your problem, but it's rarely a good idea to use old-style classes. Also, `self.test_frame is not None` is preferred over `self.test_frame != None`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed! I was getting confused because of `self.lmain`. Here is the working code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class CamView():  
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.window = tk.Toplevel(parent)

        self.lmain2 = tk.Label(self.window)
        self.lmain2.pack()

        self.window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close) 
        self.show_frame()

    def show_frame(self):
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.parent.img)
        self.lmain2.imgtk = imgtk
        self.lmain2.configure(image=imgtk)

    def close(self):
        self.parent.test_frame = None
        self.window.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: root.quit())

class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.lmain = tk.Label(parent)
        self.lmain.pack()

        self.test_frame = None
        frame = tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        a = tk.Label(text='hello!').pack()
        b = tk.Button(frame, text='open', command=self.load_window)
        b.pack()

        width, height = 800, 600
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
        self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)

        self.do_stuff()

    def do_stuff(self):
        _, frame = self.cap.read()
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        self.img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
        if self.test_frame != None:
            self.test_frame.show_frame()
        self.lmain.after(10, self.do_stuff)

    def load_window(self):
        if self.test_frame == None:
            self.test_frame = CamView(self)

control = Main(root)
root.mainloop()
```